# Finding all edges joining nodes within a set of nodes in postgres

Tags: postgresql, graph-theory, hierarchical-data

I have data stored in two tables called objects and object_relationships.
It's a simple self referential many to many.

Objects table

| id | description | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Subject: an email about birds | email |
| 2 | Subject: birds | email |
| 3 | john | person |
| 4 | mark | person |
| 5 | lex | person |
| 6 | Subject: ants | email |

words between tables to fix SE formatting

Object_relationships table

| object_id | child_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | to |
| 3 | 1 | from |
| 6 | 4 | to |
| 5 | 4 | family |
| 2 | 5 | from |
| 5 | 3 | friends |

Using an initial query like

```
select * from objects where description like '%birds%' or description like '%lex%' or description like '%john%'
```

Returns id's [1, 2, 3, 5]

I then want every edge between these "nodes"
specifically:

- 1 - to - 3
- 3 - from - 1
- 2 - from - 5
- 5 - friends - 3

The code I have for the getting the edges using joins but it's wrong because it pulls in new nodes and I can't figure out how to exclude nodes outside the initial query.

I think my approach is wrong because the query does not even consider the parents of the objects. The json build object is to quickly plot the output in any cytoscape compatible viewer

```
json_build_object(
    'source', base.object_id,
    'target', base.child_id,
    'type', base.child_type
) as edge1,
json_build_object(
    'source', base.child_id,
    'target', base.child2_id,
    'type', base.child2_type
) as edge2 from
(
with parent as (
select
    distinct unnest(array[base.object_id, base.child_id, base.child2_id]) as id
from
    (
    select 
                o.id as object_id,
                o.type,
                or1.child_object_id as child_id,
                or1."type" as child_type
                or2.child_object_id as child2_id,
                or2."type" as child2_type
    from
        objects o
    join object_relationships or1 on
        or1.object_id = o.id
    join objects o1 on
        o1.id = or1.child_object_id
    join object_relationships or2 on or2.object_id = o1.id
    join objects o2 on o2.id = or2.child_object_id
    where
        o.description like '%birds%' or o.description like '%lex%' or o.description like '%john%'
    limit 1) base
limit 100)
select
    o.id as object_id,
    or1.child_object_id as child_id,
    or1."type" as child_type,
    or2.child_object_id as child2_id,
    or2."type" as child2_type
from
    parent p
join objects o on
    o.id = p.id
join object_relationships or1 on
    or1.object_id = o.id
join objects o1 on
    o1.id = or1.child_object_id
join object_relationships or2 on
    or2.object_id = o1.id
join objects o2 on
    o2.id = or2.child_object_id
limit 100) base;
```

Comment: The second table formats correctly in the question preview. Not sure how to fix it in this post.

Comment: Why not just `SELECT * FROM object_relationships WHERE object_id IN (1, 2, 3, 5) AND child_id IN (1, 2, 3, 5)` (with a subquery instead of the hardcoded lists, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an array of `ids` from `object` table and search rows in `object_relationships` by elements of the array.

```sql
select object_id, type, child_id
from (
    select array_agg(id) as ids
    from objects 
    where description like any('{%birds%, %lex%, %john%}')
    ) s
join object_relationships
on object_id = any(ids) and child_id = any(ids)
order by object_id, child_id;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kZDthCZx).

Comment: Thank you! This works well and it's fast enough for my use case. 450 pairs in 2.5 seconds, 6500 pairs in 5.4 seconds and 10000 in 13 seconds with indexes.

Comment: Bergi's suggestion in the commentary is accurate (generating all pairs would make sense if, for example, the order mattered). I corrected the query, it should be much faster. Thanks @Bergi.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said pairs in the comment. The initial answer including the direction and edge label was correct for my use case.

Comment: @C-mon - that's OK. I just think both queries do the same but the newer one is faster.